# How can I get the year, day, minute, hour, and second of Date.now() using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I dont really know how to approach this question, I know that Date.now() returns the amount of milliseconds since the unix epoch (jan 1st 1970) but how can I get the current date and hour using this?

Comment: Have you read the mdn documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything special in using Node, you can still use Date cause it's a standard built-in object.

When you create a new instance of date, it indeed returns "*the amount of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1st 1970)*", you are right! However, this format cannot be useful if you want to use another format of date.

In **UTC** (Coordinated Universal Time) for example, today is: Tuesday, March 9, 2021.

Checking the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you can see that there's a lot of stuff to be done in terms of date manipulation. It only depends on what you want. To get the day, month and year using UTC convention, simply:

```js
const today = new Date()

const day = today.getUTCDate()
const month = today.getUTCMonth() + 1 // don't forget +1
const year = today.getUTCFullYear()

const hour = today.getUTCHours()
const minutes = today.getUTCMinutes()

const zeroPad = (num) => String(num).padStart(2, '0')

console.log(`UTC: ${today.toUTCString()}`)
console.log(`Today is: ${zeroPad(month)}/${zeroPad(day)}/${year} at ${zeroPad(hour)}:${zeroPad(minutes)}`)
```

Comment: Very nice, perfect answer!